# How to run ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING on specific rows only

Tags: teradata, cumulative-sum

I have an SQL query that is calculating the running total of 2 columns. Every week, there is new data which will be added to `DUMMY_TABLE` and everytime when I run the `running total` for that table, it will calculate the running total of all preceding rows which I don't really need. I just need the running total for the data that has been newly inserted. It will be a waste of resource if I have to run the total of all previous rows. I would like to know if there is any way to return the running total only for the week newly inserted.

I tried to use `where` but it filters the data. The reason I am looking for this is if I have new data every week and the table is size of 10K records, the `running total` will re-calculate all the 10K records and the new data I inserted.

```
SELECT 
RID,
FYFW,
VOL,
FAILED_VOL,
SUM(VOL) OVER (PARTITION BY RID, SUBSTR(TRIM(FYFW), 1, 4)   ORDER BY RID,FYFW  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS YTD_VOL,
SUM(FAILED_VOL) OVER (PARTITION BY RID, SUBSTR(TRIM(FYFW), 1, 4)   ORDER BY RID,FYFW  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS YTD_FAILED_VOL,
FROM DUMMY_TABLE
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

[image]

Comment: To be able to calculate the running total you *must* start with the 1st row. Unless you have a very high number of rows this is usually quite efficient. The only way to avoid this is storing those values as columns and calculating it during load. Btw, no need to add `RID` to Order By as it's already partitioned by it.

Comment: @dnoeth when you say high number of rows, are we talking about millions of rows?

Comment: Lots of millions :-)